# Paypal Php- VALIDATION ERROR

Tags: php, paypal

I am getting this error while sending a paypal request:

> 400{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"redirect_urls.cancel_url","issue":"This field required when payment_method is 'paypal'"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"cfab4d06737bf"}exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:154 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(73): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(565): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 D:\xampp\htdocs\prince2\checkout.php(70): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 {main}

Comment: problem is in - redirect_urls. Did you set this within paypal?

Comment: i set that in my php code.. here is my the redirectUrl code in my php code

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
 $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=true')
     ->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL.'/pay.php?success=false');

Comment: thanks sir @VinodKumar i already fixed this :D